# Função Javascript não executa quando seleciono um radio button

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Criei uma função Javascript que precisa ser executada toda vez que um dos botões do radio button é selecionado. Mas nada acontece. Segue o código:

```
<script>
            document.write( )
            function mostraCampoArray(int numeroDoCampo){
                var vetor = new Array()
                vetor[0]= "Posição zero do vetor"
                vetor[1] = "Posição um do vetor"
                vetor[2] = "Posição dois do vetor"
                vetor[3] = "Posição três do vetor"
                document.write(vetor[numeroDoCampo])
            }
</script>
```

RadioButton:

```
     <input type="radio" name="Posição" value=0  onClick="mostraCampoArray(value)"> Posição 0 do array
    <input type="radio" name="Posição" value=1  onClick="mostraCampoArray(value)"> Posição 1 do array
    <input type="radio" name="Posição" value=2  onClick="mostraCampoArray(value)"> Posição 2 do array
    <input type="radio" name="Posição" value=3  onClick="mostraCampoArray(value)"> Posição 3 do array
```

Não sei se a sintaxe da chamada da função no onClick do RadioButton está correta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está em `function mostraCampoArray(int numeroDoCampo)`.

O *JavaScript* é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca, ou seja, não é necessário informar o tipo da variável, como em `Java`, `GoLang` etc.

O correto é:

```
function mostraCampoArray(numeroDoCampo){
  var vetor = new Array()
  vetor[0] = "Posição zero do vetor"
  vetor[1] = "Posição um do vetor"
  vetor[2] = "Posição dois do vetor"
  vetor[3] = "Posição três do vetor"
  document.write(vetor[numeroDoCampo])
}
```

Comment: É verdade. Esqueci disso. Esse é o meu segundo exercício em Javascript, tem coisas básicas que não decorei ainda... Obrigado!